# #using <System.Numerics.Vectors.dll> fails C++CLI

Tags: c#, c++-cli

`#using <System.Numerics.Vectors.dll>` causes an error in my C++CLI code, *cannot open metadata file "System.Numerics.Vectors.dll"*. From [searches](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/ba51e381-3d90-4439-95ad-b9330456473d/unable-to-install-systemnumericsvectors?forum=visualstudiogeneral), I found that it happens because System.Numerics.Vectors package does not support native platform. I wonder why they simply don't support this library even for C++CLI which is running upon CLR. Any reasons?

p.s. I'm using .NET4.6.1 and VS2017.

Comment: Something does not add up. Your linked questions is about compilation to "native,Version=v0.0", not CLI. It is doing something around what NGEN does. Creating *NON* CLI/Native Code from C# or generally managed C++. | The basic structure of a .NET Executeable is a lot of IL to be interpreted by a CLI, with some native Bootstrap code to load the CLI into the .exe. NGEN just makes a full on Native .exe, with none of the interpretation need - but also none of the advantages.

Comment: But it's possible to import System.Numerics and C++CLI does not complain anything about it. What's the difference though?

Comment: It is a simple file-not-found error.  Easiest way to get ahead is to copy the DLL into the directory that contains your project file.  Or don't use #using but instead right-click the project's References node and click Add Reference, Browse button.  Or edit Project > Properties > VC++ Directories > Reference Directories setting.

Comment: I might be misunderstanding but I couldn't find System.Numerics.dll and System.Numerics.Vectors.dll files in evaluated path to Reference Directories.